# I am facing a problem trying to use joyride and trying to navigate to different pages ,

Tags: angular, angularjs, zurb-joyride

I am able to route to different page over here but i am not able to get tour card once I navigate to next page

async opentour() {
await this.joyrideService
.startTour(
{
themeColor: "#00000",
steps: [
"step1",
"step2",
"step3@next page",
],
stepDefaultPosition: "left",
} // Your steps order
)
.subscribe({
next: (step) => {
this.currentStep = step.name;
if (
this.currentStep == "step1" ||
this.currentStep == "step2"
){
this.dropdown.open();}
console.log(step);
},

```
    complete: () => {
      console.log("Tour finished");
    },
  });
```

}